# Pyodbc slow while fetching records

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

Hi I am using pyodbc to fetch some data from sql server 2012. The table I am querying has 11000 rows in it. But my read time is too slow. Its around 5 minutes. 
I tried fetchall, fetchmany option with arraysize defined but still the taken is around 5 minutes. And I also tried with python 3.6. But the result is same.

The source table has 10 varchar(10) fields.

I am using **pyodbc: 4.0.27, python: 3.7.5**

My code is simple.

```
con = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server};Server=test;Database=test;Trusted_Connection=yes;")

statement = """select * from test"""
cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute(statement)
for row in cur:
    count += 1
```

Comment: What is in sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks filtered by your session when you are fetching rows?

Comment: blocking_task_address, blocking_session_id, blocking_exec_context_id all these fileds are null.

Comment: I did not ask about blocking_* columns, what is wait type

Comment: There are 20 distinct wait types. But REQUEST_FOR_DEADLOCK_SEARCH, CHECKPOINT_QUEUE, ONDEMAND_TASK_QUEUE, SP_SERVER_DIAGNOSTICS_SLEEP, LOGMGR_QUEUE are the ones with resource address.

Comment: you do NOT filter for you session. And I think you do not query dm_os_waiting_tasks but waiting_stats and it's not what Im asking for

Comment: Ok, I looked in sys.dm_exec_requests and found out that the wait_type is null. The last_wait_type is async_network_IO

Comment: async_network means it's your client application that is slow to consume the records

Comment: That means it's the fault of pyodbc?

Comment: This means there is no problem with SQL Server. It can be network problem or it can be client problem

Comment: I re-implemented the whole thing using JDBC. I have no such problems now. I couldn't figure out the exact problem with pyodbc because network is quite good.

Comment: >>>or it can be client problem<<< It's not necessarily network, this type of wait means the server did it's best but the client is too slow to consume the result. It just means that there is no problem on the server side